# Error installing rhc: net-scp requires net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, runtime)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to install Open shift's client tool to access apps on OpenShift. But I get the following error when I try to install rhc:

```
Error installing rhc:   net-scp requires net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, runtime)
```

Couldn't find much help online to resolve this error.

[I'm using an old MacBook running SnowLeopard.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Snow Leopard comes with net-ssh 2.0.4 installed. Try running `sudo gem update net-ssh` in terminal to update net-ssh, then try installing rhc again.

You may want to just run `sudo gem update` to get all of your RubyGems up to date.